# how to execute jquery function after one another (and few more questions)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

To explain the situation ,I am using both jquery and animate.css combined in order to bring about some animation part that i want to apply to my website.

http://lifeto.cafe24.com/xe/

I have a couple of questions in this post, and it needs fairly thorough understanding of the site that i have built.

Fist, If you go to the webstie I linked above and click on the menu that says '공지사항' on the bottom, an iframe src gets triggered by jquery attr.

And if you click on any of the image you can see on the board after that, the board content (#window_frame) slidesout to left and the new div (.window_board) slides in from the leftside.

but when you click on the image, notice the content of the board AND the .window_board disappear and appear AT THE SAME TIME.

what i want to achieve here is to have the #window_frame slides out first, and THEN, after it is done, have .window_board slides in.

and SECONDLY, when i click on the menu button that says '공지사항' from the point when the .window_board is still opened, i want the .window_board to slides back in, and have the content(#window_frame) comes back out.

I wonder if it's possible to achieve this only by using simple jquery events, as it needs to calculate when the #window_frame is opened or not.

here is the complete js for the board (iframe)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(document).on('click', '.item', function() {
jQuery('.loader_container', parent.document.body).show();
var url = jQuery(this).data('url');
jQuery('#window_board', parent.document.body).attr('src', 'url',200);
    jQuery('#window_frame', parent.document.body).addClass('animated slideOutLeft');
   jQuery('.window_board', parent.document.body).addClass('open animated slideInLeft');
  jQuery('.loader_container', parent.document.body).hide();

  });
  });
```

and the main menu:

```
<a onclick="jQuery('#window_frame').attr('src', 
'http://lifeto.cafe24.com{$val1['href']}',200),    
jQuery('#window_frame').removeClass('animated slideOutLeft')"  class="menu_a">MENU</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Your question not clear so much, but if i consider only your main question:*

**how to execute jquery function after one another**

you can use `promise().done()` or `.when()` to execute a jquery function after another.

**Example:**

```
$('div').click(function(){
$(this).addClass('blah').promise().done(function(){
alert('class added!');
});
});
```

You can read more about it:

https://api.jquery.com/promise/

Comment: thanks for the convenient answer. could you please take a look at the script and tell me why this is not working though? https://jsfiddle.net/vxppzmfp/2/ it is applied to the same live site.

Comment: Well, few things, in this example on JSFiddle, first you must choose jQuery library, then you should not use `jquery('id or class')` instead of it, you can use `$(' id or class')` and there is no html code, i made these changes on your code, try again on this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vxppzmfp/4/)

Comment: just to make things clear, the usage of jQuery, and $ doesn't make any difference here. I have only used 'jQuery' so that it doesn't collide with other programs that are using $ selector in my case it being a CMS. and i only fiddled the script to let you know that there is no error in this coding. but thanks for your answer.